# Array returning indexOf rather than count of pattern

Tags: javascript

So I've edited my code a bit and I'm stuck trying to the count the number of times a pattern occurs in a specified record.

I would like the array to return as *2,1,0* if something like **in** is searched but currently all I get is *13,19,-1*.

I would really appreciate any hints on how to improve my code.

```
books = [
    {
    title: "Inheritance: Inheritance Cycle, Book 4",
    author: "Christopher Paolini",
    },
{
    title: "The Sense of an Ending",
    author: "Julian Barnes"},
{
    title: "Snuff Discworld Novel 39",
    author: "Sir Terry Pratchett",
    }
]
search = prompt("Title?");

function count(books, pattern) {

        var num = 0;
        var result = [];
        for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
            var index = books[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase());
            do {
                result[i] = index;
                index = books[i].title.toLowerCase().indexOf(pattern.toLowerCase(), index + 1);
            }
            while (index >= 0)
            num = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }
alert(count(books, search));
```

Comment: You forgot to declare "i" with `var` !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be keeping the count, not the index at which it was found in result.  You should increment the count only if the index is greater than or equal to zero.  Note I've made a few optimizations as well to reduce the number of times you need to transform the strings.  I've also added a different version that uses regular expressions.

```
function count(books, pattern) {
    var result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var index = -1, // set to -1 so that the first iteration will set it to 0
            title = books[i].title.toLowerCase(),
            realPattern = pattern.toLowerCase();
        result[i] = 0;
        do {
            index = title.indexOf(pattern, index + 1);
            if (index >= 0) {
               result[i] = result[i] + 1;
            }
        }
        while (index >= 0)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Better alternative

```
RegExp.escape = function(text) {
    return text.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&");
}

function count(books, pattern) {
    var result = [];
    for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(pattern),'gi'),
            matches = books[i].title.match(regex);
        result[i] = matches ? matches.length : 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the regex (I wonder why I didn't think of that). Anyways, you should mention that the pattern might have to be escaped for special characters and you need the `g`lobal modifier.

Comment: @FelixKling I've updated it using some escape code I found at http://80.68.89.23/2006/Jan/20/escape/

Comment: I've tried to use records with your example but keep getting [Object object] as the output http://jsfiddle.net/MyBZE/

Comment: I meant you need the `g` modifier here: `var regex = new RegExp(RegExp.escape(pattern),'i')` :) (otherwise it will only match once)

Comment: @methuselah: That's to be expected, because `record` is an object. `alert` is the wrong tool for debugging, use `console.log` (works in Chrome, needs Firebug in Firefox, don't know about IE).

Comment: @FelixKling any suggestions on how to display the records on **return**? http://jsfiddle.net/MyBZE/

Comment: @methuselah: Normally you would iterate over the object or array, access each record and print it the way you like it.

Comment: @methuselah that code is doing something completely different.  You don't need the inner looping stuff to just find the matching entries and return each entry.  See http://jsfiddle.net/n7qeB/

Answer (score 1):

You can use a for in loop and push the loop var into your results variable.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQuDK/)

```
var arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'];

function count(books, pattern) {   
    var results = [];
    for (var index in arr) {
        if (arr[index] === pattern) {
          results.push(index);
        } 
    }
    return results;
}

console.log(count(arr, 'a'));
```

Comment: That's not what the OP wants. He wants to count the occurrences of a substring in a string.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it's very simple**:

```
function count(books, pattern) 
{

var num = 0;
var result = Array();
for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) 
{
    var times = books[i].title.toLowerCase().split(pattern.toLowerCase());
    if(times.length - 1 >= 0)result[i] = times.length - 1;
}
return result;
}
```

Hope you'll find this usefull!

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify your code a lot by using `match`. I made a jsfiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/NTWNn/ it looks like this :

```
var books = [
    {
        title: "Inheritance: Inheritance Cycle, Book 4",
        author: "Christopher Paolini",
    },
    {
        title: "The Sense of an Ending",
        author: "Julian Barnes"
    },
    {
        title: "Snuff Discworld Novel 39",
        author: "Sir Terry Pratchett",
    }
]
search = prompt("Title?");

function count(pattern)
{
    var results = [];
    var matches = null;
    pattern = new RegExp(pattern, "g")

    for (i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
        results[i] = 0;
        matches = books[i].title.toLowerCase().match(pattern);
        if(matches != null) {
            results[i] = matches.length;
        }
    }
    return results
}

alert(count(search))
```